# Swiping 2 array elements in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to swipe 2 elements in python. When the element it self is a single number, it works. But when the element it self is an array, it fails. Could anyone please tell me the reason for this? I appreciate your help. Details are listed below.

```
import numpy as np

# Section 1
points = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
temp = points[0]
points[0] = points[1]
points[1] = temp

print(points)
# This will print [2 1 3 4] and it works

# Section 2
points = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]])
temp = points[0]
points[0] = points[1]
points[1] = temp

# This will print 
#[[2 3]
# [2 3]
# [3 4]] which fails
```

I am wondering why it fails when using the same approach. I tried to change `temp = points[0]` in Section 2 to `temp = points[0].copy()` and it works. But since `temp`  get the element in the first place. Why it changes in later line `points[1] = temp`?

Answer (score 2):

When you have an numpy array with more than 1 dimension, then indexing into it with an integer **returns a view**.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
>>> arr
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])
>>> row_view = arr[0]
>>> row_view
array([0, 1])
>>> row_view.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
```

Note, OWNDATA is false!

```
>>> arr[0, 1] = 99
>>> arr
array([[ 0, 99],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9]])
>>> row_view
array([ 0, 99])
>>> row_view[0] = -99
>>> row_view
array([-99,  99])
>>> arr
array([[-99,  99],
       [  2,   3],
       [  4,   5],
       [  6,   7],
       [  8,   9]])
```

Whenever you index into an individual element, numpy returns a new, "boxed" object that is independent:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> x = arr[0]
>>> x.shape
()
>>> x
0
>>> x.flags
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : False
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
```

Comment: That is a thoughtful answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you do `temp = points[0]`, you are creating a reference to the first row of the an array, rather than creating a new array with the same values. Thus any changes made to `points` afterwards will change `temp`.

This behavior is specific to numpy arrays (also torch and tensorflow tensors), and it does not apply to native python lists.